# We have $10^6$ people equally divided between two candidates. How big does $N$ have to be to make candidate $A$'s chance of winning $99.75\%$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Suppose that $n=10^{6}$ people are nearly equally divided between two candidates, $A$ and $B$. Assume each person votes independently with probability $p=1/2$ for each candidate.

Problem+Solution A) The mean number of votes for $A$ will be $np = 10^6 \times (1/2) = 500000$
and sigma (standard deviation) will be $\sqrt{np(1-p)} =  500$.

Problem B) Let $Z$ be a standard normal, and $P(Z>z) = 0.025$. Find $z$. Solution: using the Z-table we have $z = 1.96$.

Problem C) Among the voters, there is a group of $N$ voters who can be highly motivated to vote for candidate A. How big does $N$ have to be to make the chance the candidate wins to be at least $99.75\%$?

Tthis part is where I'm having trouble with. I figure we let $N = mean + stand \times Z$ , so if we find the z score for $P(z > 99.75) = 2.81$. Thus, $N = 500,000 + 500 \times 2.81$.

However, the on the answer key, the answer is $N = 500,000 + 500\times 1.96$.

How is this the case when when we want it to be at least $99.75\%$? Why are we using a $z$ score of $1.96$?

Also, I tried using the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when trying my equations, but it is not working for me

Comment: I won't consider the first sentence "... are nearly equally divided" to be equivalent to the second sentence that boils down to "... make their choice by tossing a coin"

Comment: In the problem they are very very equally divided so it is assumed the probability to be ½.

Comment: Going forward, with your future postings, please make more of an effort to successfully use MathJax.

Comment: I tried using the notation mentioned in the last sentence. For example writing 10^{6} isn't showing properly for me. I'm not sure how you guys are getting it to work.

Comment: Add dollar signs. Use `$10^{6}$` for example.

Comment: I wonder if someone got confused about the decimal point while making the problem and the answer sheet. $P(Z>z) = 0.025$ gives you a $97.5\%$ chance that $Z<z.$ You are correct that $P(Z>z) = 0.0025$ is required for a $99.75\%$ chance.

Comment: The "highly motivated" part seems incredibly ill-defined. Why do we need so many "highly-motivated" voters? If we know that a voter is going to vote for candidate $A$ for sure, then $500,001$ such voters would give $A$ a victory with probability $1.$ If "highly motivated" doesn't mean the voter is sure to vote for $A$, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $X\sim Bin(10^6,0.5)$ votes for $A$. Approximate this with $Y=(X-500000)/500$ and $Y\approx N(0,1)=:Z$. Since $$P(Z\ge -2.81)=99.75\%,$$ we have approximately $$P(X\ge 500000 - 500 \times 2.81)=99.75\%.$$

So you have to bribe $500\times2.81$ non-voters to make this the case. If you're bribing existing voters, half of them will already be $A$-voters, but the other half will make $B$ lose votes, so you end up with the same solution.